# How to delete clicked Widget?

Tags: kivy

I create child widgets (Buttons for example).
When I click each button (each child widget) I wish to remove the clicked widget from parent.children.

I can't figure out how to fetch that specific clicked widget from parent.children other than having a clumsy system in parent:

```
def DeleteWidget(self, targetWidget):
    for i in self.children:
      if id(i) == id(targetWidget):
        self.remove_widget(i)
```

Any better methods to delete a clicked widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind each button's `on_press` property to your class method `DeleteWidget` like this:

```
btn1 = Button(text= "Button 1")
btn1.bind(on_press = self.DeleteWidget)
```

When `btn1` is pressed, it'll execute your `DeleteWidget` method which will take an argument (in this case, button object with its address).

```
def DeleteWidget(self, *args):
    self.remove_widget(args[0])
```

Here's a basic example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import *
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import *

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):        
        bx = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')        
        btn1 = Button(text="Button 1")
        btn1.bind(on_press = self.deleteButton)
        bx.add_widget(btn1)
        btn2 = Button(text="Button 2")
        btn2.bind(on_press = self.deleteButton)
        bx.add_widget(btn2)
        return bx

    def deleteButton(self, x):
        self.root.remove_widget(x)

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.